# Same computer, new domain. Windows easy transfer does not list old domain account

Tags: windows-domain, windows-easy-transfer

We recently switched to a new domain here at the office. We are using the same machines (windows 7 ultimate x64), just changed to new domains (removed machine from old domain, joined new domain). I want to transfer all my settings (still on the same machine - old user profile account) to this new profile I am currently logged in with. When I run the Windows easy transfer tool, the old domain account isn't listed! How can I transfer my settings from the old domain account to my new domain account on this same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into the old domain, run WET, save data, log into new domain, run WET, restore data.

If you detached from old domain before running WET, you may have to rejoin it to perform the "this is my old computer" step first.